# How to handle different asserts based on template types

Tags: c++, unit-testing, templates, googletest

At the moment I'm writing a unit test with google test for an generic class (template) using TYPED_TEST. The problem I have to resolve is that my class produce different results depending on the data type. The tests cannot take the data type into account. And I do not want to write a test for each data type.

OK, let me explain this in a very simple context.
For example we have a calculator class in Calculator.h:

```cpp
#pragma once

template <typename T>
class Calculator
{
public:
    Calculator()
        : _value(0)
    {
    }


    T Add(T valA, T valB)
    {
        _value = valA + valB;
        return _value;
    }

    T Add(T val)
    {
        _value += val;
        return _value;
    }

private:
    T _value;
};
```

And here is my test:

```cpp
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include "Calculator.h"

template <typename T>
class CalculatorTestFixture : public testing::Test
{
public:
    void SetUp() override
    {

    }

    void TearDown() override
    {

    }

    Calculator<T> _calculator;
};


typedef testing::Types<int, float> TypesToTest;

TYPED_TEST_CASE(CalculatorTestFixture, TypesToTest);

TYPED_TEST(CalculatorTestFixture, TestTypes)
{
    // ARRANGE
    TypeParam val1 = (TypeParam)1.8;
    TypeParam val2 = (TypeParam)1.2;
    TypeParam testVal = (TypeParam)0;
    TypeParam expectedVal = (TypeParam)3.0;

    // ACT
    testVal = this->_calculator.Add(val1, val2);
     
    // ASSERT
    ASSERT_EQ(expectedVal, testVal);
}
```

The test for data type **int** will fail, because the class calculates 1+1=2 and thats what I expect for this data type.

Is there a nice solution like in parametric tests, where I can additional define the expected output values for data types or should I write tests for each supported data types?

Comment: "The tests cannot take the data type into account." seems to contradict what you ask for

Comment: Your expectation is wrong, instead of `(TypeParam)3.0`, it should be something like `(((TypeParam)1.8) + ((TypeParam)1.2))` or simply `val1 + val2`.

Comment: You can still create overload `int some_value(Tag<int>) {return 2;} double some_value(Tag<double>) {return 3.;}` and use something like ` TypeParam expectedVal = some_value(Tag<TypeParam>{});`.

Answer (score 1):

Template specializing is working for me. I moved the expected value into an abstract method which returns the expected result. With template specialization, it is posible to solve the type dependend result.

```cpp
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include "Calculator.h"

template <typename T>
class CalculatorTestFixture : public testing::Test
{
public:
    void SetUp() override
    {
        _val1 = (T)1.8;
        _val2 = (T)1.2;
    }

    void TearDown() override
    {

    }

    T expectedResult()
    {
        return (T)0;
    }

    Calculator<T> _calculator;
    T _val1;
    T _val2;
};


int CalculatorTestFixture<int>::expectedResult()
{
    return 2;
}

float CalculatorTestFixture<float>::expectedResult()
{
    return 3.0f;
}


typedef testing::Types<int, float> TypesToTest;

TYPED_TEST_CASE(CalculatorTestFixture, TypesToTest);

TYPED_TEST(CalculatorTestFixture, TestTypes)
{
    // ARRANGE
    TypeParam testVal = (TypeParam)0;
    TypeParam expectedVal = this->expectedResult();

    // ACT
    testVal = this->_calculator.Add(this->_val1, this->_val2);
     
    // ASSERT
    ASSERT_EQ(expectedVal, testVal);
}
```